# Can't grasp how to join 2 tables in LINQ extension

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables that I need to join with each other but I can't grasp how I can join them using a linq extension.

I can do it easy in SQL, but I'm struggling with linq.

My problem - 2 models:

```
public class GamesNight
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string GamesNightTitle { get; set;}
        public string GamesNightDescription { get; set; }
        public string GamesNightLocation { get; set; }
        public DateTime GamesNightDate { get; set; }
}
```

and an attendance model:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }  
    public virtual GamesNight GamesNight { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty simple to grasp, the user 'attends' a 'gamesnight'.

I have a view model that reads

```
public class UpcomingGamesNightViewModel
{
    public GamesNight GamesNight { get; set; }
    public bool Attending { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a built up array of `UpcomingGamesNightViewModel` where the `GamesNight` a gamesnight and attending is where the user is attending the games night via the attending table.

Thanking you!

Comment: LINQ's .Join method does a inner join per default. Either use .DefaultIfEmpty method for left outer join or add an inverse navigation property so you can eagerly load the related tuples

Comment: @Ceri, Main problem is in the relationship between your entities. Its not clear to me. Please clearly explain the relationships among `GamesNight`, `ApplicationUser` and `Attendance` then also ask your requirements clearly!

Comment: You don't tell which type of data layer you're using, but I think `GamesNight` should have a navigation property `Attendances`.